# Invisible views detection on motion event

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, motionevent, android-viewgroup

As i  already tried views with motion drag reading [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).
 I have clearly not saying about basics of it but i want to hide or`invisible` view which will be visible when other `view` which is being `dragged` or using `motion` can taken to the hidden or`invisible` `surface` area ?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, why aint you using `View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` ?

Comment: Can you put a image or a small video of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Set tag of to view and  after that when you touch view check tag of that view in **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** or **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** and set **View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)** for other views.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be easy using transparent color for this View. Even you will use ViewGroup with other elements, you can just create method for updating parameters (like background, color, image, etc.) to the transparent type.